# cellpadding is missing on FACEBOX

Tags: facebox

I'm using facebox ( https://github.com/defunkt/facebox ) with same code downloaded from github without any modification except remote.html

I JUST added this code in remote.htmlTABLE in facebox window with this code:

Hello
        World
    
    
        I'm remote.html, a different file loaded with ajax.
        I'm remote.html, a different file loaded with ajax.

PROBLEM: There is NO CELLPADDING on facebox window.

How can I solve this problem?

OR ANY OTHER SOLUTION TO REPLACE WITH FACEBOX?

Regards,
Nuri Akman

Answer (score 0):

It's because the facebox.css file contains this:

```
#facebox table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Remove it or override it with other CSS.

Answer (score 0):

On version Facebox 1.3 add this code in facebox.css:

```
 #facebox .content table tr td { padding: 4px; }
 #facebox .content table tr th { padding: 4px; }
 #facebox .content table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px; }
```